# React-Navigation Reset while Passing Props to Children

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `React-Navigation` with `React-Native`. I get different results for identical code executed at different points of the stack. My Router uses a mix of `Stack Navigators` and `Tab Navigators.` Here's the structure:

- **StackNav:**

  - Login
  - Register
  - Home

    - **TabsNav:**

      - Tab One
      - Tab Two

**Login** is the first screen the user sees. From here, They can log in and go to **Home => Tab One** OR they can **Register**. From **Register** They can then go to **Home => Tab One**

On both the **Login** and **Register** screens, I make an API call before navigating to **Home => Tab One**

When I navigate I want to reset the Stack and also pass the same `props` to **Tab One** and **Tab Two**

Here is my navigation code in **Login**:

```
    const actions = [
      NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: "Home"
          })
        ]
      }),
      NavigationActions.setParams({
        key: 'Tab Two',
        params: {data: responseJson.data}
      }),
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'Tab One',
        params: {data: responseJson.data}
      })
    ];
    actions.forEach(this.props.navigation.dispatch);
```

In **Tab One**, the params don't get passed to `this.props.navigation.state`. After hunting a bit, I discovered that I can access the params by going to `this.props.navigation.dispatch.arguments`

In **Tab Two**, the params get passed to `this.props.navigation.state`

Here is my navigation code for **Register** (*it's identical to Login*):

```
    const actions = [
      NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: "Home"
          })
        ]
      }),
      NavigationActions.setParams({
        key: 'Tab Two',
        params: {data: responseJson.data}
      }),
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'Tab One',
        params: {data: responseJson.data}
      })
    ];
    actions.forEach(this.props.navigation.dispatch);
```

Now, in **Tab One**, the params can be found in `this.props.navigation.state`. In **Tab Two** the params do not get passed at all. They do not appear neither in `this.props.navigation.state`(I only get the `routeName` and `key`) or `this.props.navigation.dispatch.arguments` (this appears as null)

I want to be able to access my data/props from this.props.navigation.state. My code is the the same in both places yet my results differ. Not sure what is going on. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

PS: I need to reset the stack. Everything works normally if I just navigate in a normal way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug of React-navigation, you can track this and try some workarounds on this github issue : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/143

It seems version `1.0.0-beta.21` works, you can give a try to this.

You can also try to use the `init` action instead of `navigate` when resetting the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the newest version 1.1.1 resolved my issues.